# What is the difference between Callable concept and the std::is_function type traits?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

C++17 will have a [`Callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) concept and I was wondering what was exactly the difference with the types for which [`std::is_function<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) is `true`. Are they equivalent? Is one a superset of the other?

Comment: well, an object with overloaded `operator()` is callable, but not a function

Comment: @M.M I guess the problem lies with the name. Functions *are* callable, but so are function objects. It's too bad there isn't a better name...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> C++17 will have a `Callable` concept

It's there in the standard since C++11.

> Are they equivalent? Is one a superset of the other?

No, in fact, they are completely disjoint. `Callable` applies only to object types, and include everything from pointer-to-members to types with an overloaded `operator()` to types with an implicit conversion to function pointers to function pointers themselves.

`is_function` is true only for actual function types, which are, by definition, not object types.

Comment: Doesn't `Callable` apply to functions too?

Comment: @NeilKirk No, not by the standard. See [\[func.wrap.func\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func#2) ("A callable object f of type F is Callable..."), [\[func.def\]/3-4](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#func.def-3) ("A callable type is a function object type or a pointer to member. A callable object is an object of a callable type."), and [\[function.objects\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#1)("A function object type is an object type that can be the type of the postfix-expression in a function call.")

Comment: LWG is [likely to adjust the wording here](http://wg21.link/lwg2393), but not in a way that affects this answer (except perhaps renaming `Callable` to `Lvalue-Callable`).